# IGNORECASE in file comparison with awk

Tags: awk, ignore-case

Here is my code:

```
'FNR==NR {a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4]++; next} !a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $5]' comparegam.txt workstudyusers1.csv >noidea6.txt
```

it is doing exactly what I need except I need to ignorecase. I have tried using IGNORECASE=1 in various places but I cant get it to work. it either fails, gives me zero results, or ignores it all together. I tried using BEGIN [IGNORECASE = 1} with no luck.

any help would be appreciated, I am at a lost. I am running this in a terminal window, not from a bash script yet. that is the end goal

Note: Output has to contain case to match original files

Here is the exact code that I have tried with IGNORECASE:

```
awk -F, 'IGNORECASE=1 FNR==NR {a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4]++; next} !a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $5]' comparegam.txt workstudyusers1.csv >noidea6.txt
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {IGNORECASE=1} {a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4]++; next} !a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $5]' comparegam.txt workstudyusers1.csv >noidea6.txt
awk -F, '{IGNORECASE = 1} FNR==NR {a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4]++; next} !a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $5]' comparegam.txt workstudyusers1.csv >noidea6.txt
awk -F, 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} FNR==NR {a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4]++; next} !a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $5]' comparegam.txt workstudyusers1.csv >noidea6.txt
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {{IGNORECASE=1} a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4]++; next} !a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $5]' comparegam.txt workstudyusers1.csv >noidea6.txt
```

and various iterations of these.

Comment: Instead of case insensitive comparison, try uppercase comparison.

Comment: Are you using gawk (GNU awk)? `IGNORECASE` is specific to gawk. You spelled it as `IGNORCASE` in the title; are you sure you spelled it correctly in your code. Copy-and-paste the exact code that's not working.

Comment: I added the different iterations I have been trying, also fixed the title. the tolower worked, but I still like to know why IGNORECASE is not working. I did awk man and IGNORECASE is listed as an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'
  FNR==NR {
    a[tolower($1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4)]++;
    next
  }
  !a[tolower($1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $5)]
' comparegam.txt workstudyusers1.csv >noidea6.txt
```

Comment: out of curiousity I noticed you changed the brackets from [ to ( around the $1 part, specific need or just preference?

Comment: @moore1emu The `()` are around the function parameters, but the `[]` are still there to index the array with the result of the `tolower` function.